# How do I configure keep-alive time between elb and server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

We are seeing 504 errors in our ELB logs, however there are no corresponding errors in the application logs. Have increased the idle timeout on ELB and can see that no requests are taking more time than that. 
Going through aws documentation found that we need to configure keep-alive time at ec2 instances to be equal or more than idle timeout to keep the connection open between elb and backend server.
Couldn't find any way to configure keep-alive time between elb and backend server. Any suggestion to do that would be helpful

We are using tomcat-ebs for backend servers.

Comment: I believe if you are using HTTP 1.1, keep-alive should be on by default. Are you sure it's the keep-alive that is messing up with it and not any network timeouts on your corporate firewall/proxy? Is the result same from any network that you access the application from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the keepAliveTimeout="xxxx" in your tomcat connector settings to avoid tearing down idle connections.